# Method request in nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, http-method

my Nginx report in error log with

```
2012/07/24 13:00:16 [notice] 19056#0: *3275841 "^(GET|HEAD|POST)$" matches "GET", client: 42.114.191.177, server: _, request: "GET /template/images/loading.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/"</code></pre>
```

And in nginx.conf

```
server {
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
        return 404;
    }
 }
```

I don't know why nginx noticed that in error_log

Answer (score 3):

Because your error log level is `notice`, `info` or `debug`.
http://nginx.org/r/error_log